# Как правильно повернуть календарь?

Tags: java, android, calendar, locale

Я не уверен, что мой подход правильный может есть другая идея?

Мне нужно имплементировать календарь в своем приложении с возможностью `Range selection` по датам.

Я для этого решил одну из самых популярных библиотек применить

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

так как знаю, что `Calendar View` не приспособлен для `Range selection`

И все работает отлично пока не нужно поменять язык приложения с Английского на Иврит (так же как и Арабский слева направо)

Название месяцев меняется название дней недели тоже, но не меняется направление последовательности (оно тоже должно быть не rtl - cправа налево , а ltr - слева направо)

Вот скрин на англ

[image]

Вот как на иврите `android:supportsRtl="false"`

[image]

И тут тоже на иврите но `android:supportsRtl="true"` (не знаю почему но кроме того, что поменялось направление стрелок больше ничего)

[image]

Я нашел такой баг фикс как раз об этом

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/pull/573

Это как раз то, что мне нужно, согласно этому фиксу направление должно меняться, но в моем случае видно, что это не так.

Что я делаю не так или подскажите, как можно это решить по другому?

Comment: Проясните момент с ссылкой на баг фикс - вы подключили либу в виде проекта, который находится в состоянии (на ветке) pull-request-а с этим фиксом или используете либу обычным способом? Если последнее - то там этого фикса нема, т.к. ПР не принят из-за конфлитка как указано в самом конце оного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать форк этого репозитория от того кто сделал этот коммит:

https://github.com/anasanasanas/material-calendarview

Придется использовать [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/)

В принципе, все предельно просто описано и на странице:

1 Пропишите:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

2 Добавьте:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.anasanasanas:material-calendarview:1.4.4'
}
```

Реультат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]